# critical section blocking (deadlock?)

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, deadlock

In the critical section of a multithreaded thread, it is not locked, but it is blocking.
It occurs frequently in 2 ~ 3 times in 10 and it is only occurred in debug build so far.
I have tested about 40,000 times in release build, but it is not reported yet.

The debugging information looks like this: In the first case, It is blocked even though the waiting thread is alone.
If you have any experience in this situation, I would appreciate your advice.

Environment
windows 7 sp1
vc ++ 2013 pro

```
0:008> !critsec 5536b5f4

CritSec CommonManager!oInstance+2c at 5536b5f4
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    4
*** Locked

0:008> dt RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION 5536b5f4
TRExecutor!RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
   +0x000 DebugInfo        : 0x0079a640 _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG
   +0x004 LockCount        : 0n-7
   +0x008 RecursionCount   : 0n0
   +0x00c OwningThread     : (null) 
   +0x010 LockSemaphore    : 0x00000234 Void
   +0x014 SpinCount        : 0

0:008> ? 0x1 & (-0n7)
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001

0:008> ? (0x2 & (-0n7)) >> 1
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000

0:008> ? ((-1) - (-0n7)) >> 2
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
```

## case 1

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  Starting New Debugger Session         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17200 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 76f30000 770b0000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 756d0000 757e0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
...
ModLoad: 762b0000 762f5000   C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
(b64.274c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=7ef8d000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=76fcf142 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=76f4000c esp=053ffb44 ebp=053ffb70 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
76f4000c cc              int     3


0:008> !ntsdexts.locks

Scanned 343 critical sections

0:008> ~8kbn
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0524ed58 76f7eb4e 00000234 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x15
01 0524edbc 76f7ea32 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x13e
02 0524ede4 0f57235e 5536b5f4 0524efcc 5536b5e8 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x150
03 0524edf8 55355b4f 0524efc0 0524efcc 00000000 mfc120ud!CCriticalSection::Lock+0x1e 
04 0524eee8 55356b2e 0000006a 0524f2ac 0524efcc CommonManager!CCommonManager::GetManager+0x3f 
05 0524efc0 00ef9f37 0000006a 0524f238 05165282 CommonManager!GetCommonManager+0x2e 
...
14 0524fbb8 76f698f2 00f9ca78 72e8944c 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
15 0524fbf8 76f698c5 00f3c170 00f9ca78 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
16 0524fc10 00000000 00f3c170 00f9ca78 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:008> !threads
Index   TID         TEB             StackBase           StackLimit          DeAlloc         StackSize           ThreadProc
0   00000e24    0x7efdd000  0x003d0000  0x003c4000  0x002d0000  0x0000c000  0x0
1   00002314    0x7efda000  0x03ab0000  0x03aaf000  0x039b0000  0x00001000  0x0
2   000020a4    0x7efd7000  0x03f70000  0x03f6e000  0x03e70000  0x00002000  0x0
3   00002f64    0x7ef9f000  0x041b0000  0x041ae000  0x040b0000  0x00002000  0x0
4   000031cc    0x7ef9c000  0x04330000  0x0432d000  0x04230000  0x00003000  0x0
5   000022a8    0x7ef99000  0x04660000  0x0465e000  0x04560000  0x00002000  0x0
6   00001e28    0x7ef96000  0x04560000  0x0455e000  0x04460000  0x00002000  0x0
7   00000688    0x7ef93000  0x04830000  0x0482e000  0x04730000  0x00002000  0x0
8   00002628    0x7ef90000  0x05250000  0x0524c000  0x05150000  0x00004000  0x0
9   0000274c    0x7ef8d000  0x05400000  0x053fc000  0x05300000  0x00004000  0x0
Total VM consumed by thread stacks 0x00022000

0:008> !handle 234 f
Handle 234
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x100003:
         Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  4
  Name          <none>
  Object Specific Information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting

0:008> !cs 5536b5f4
-----------------------------------------
Critical section   = 0x5536b5f4 (CommonManager!oInstance+0x2C)
DebugInfo          = 0x0079a640
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x234
SpinCount          = 0x00000000

0:008> !critsec 5536b5f4

CritSec CommonManager!oInstance+2c at 5536b5f4
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    4
*** Locked

0:008> dt RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION 5536b5f4
TRExecutor!RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
   +0x000 DebugInfo        : 0x0079a640 _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG
   +0x004 LockCount        : 0n-7
   +0x008 RecursionCount   : 0n0
   +0x00c OwningThread     : (null) 
   +0x010 LockSemaphore    : 0x00000234 Void
   +0x014 SpinCount        : 0

0:008> ? 0x1 & (-0n7)
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001

0:008> ? (0x2 & (-0n7)) >> 1
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000

0:008> ? ((-1) - (-0n7)) >> 2
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001
```

## case 2

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  Starting New Debugger Session         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17200 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 012b0000 01370000   D:\Binary_12.0\Newronz\Debug\TRExecutor.exe
ModLoad: 76f30000 770b0000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
...
ModLoad: 6f770000 6f775000   C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
(27b0.31a4): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=7ef8d000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=76fcf142 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=76f4000c esp=029afa94 ebp=029afac0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
76f4000c cc              int     3


0:004> !ntsdexts.locks

Scanned 372 critical sections

0:004> !threads
Index   TID         TEB             StackBase           StackLimit          DeAlloc         StackSize           ThreadProc
0   00003080    0x7efdd000  0x00440000  0x00434000  0x00340000  0x0000c000  0x0
1   00002cec    0x7efda000  0x03ac0000  0x03abf000  0x039c0000  0x00001000  0x0
2   00002cf0    0x7efd7000  0x03ee0000  0x03ede000  0x03de0000  0x00002000  0x0
3   00002f6c    0x7ef9f000  0x040d0000  0x040ce000  0x03fd0000  0x00002000  0x0
4   00002cf8    0x7ef9c000  0x041e0000  0x041de000  0x040e0000  0x00002000  0x0
5   0000260c    0x7ef99000  0x043c0000  0x043bd000  0x042c0000  0x00003000  0x0
6   00001b64    0x7ef96000  0x04690000  0x0468e000  0x04590000  0x00002000  0x0
7   00002460    0x7ef93000  0x048b0000  0x048ae000  0x047b0000  0x00002000  0x0
8   00001114    0x7ef90000  0x04ff0000  0x04feb000  0x04ef0000  0x00005000  0x0
9   000031a4    0x7ef8d000  0x029b0000  0x029ac000  0x028b0000  0x00004000  0x0
Total VM consumed by thread stacks 0x00023000

0:003> ~6kbn
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0468f1ec 76f7eb4e 00000234 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x15
01 0468f250 76f7ea32 00000000 00000000 0135cf54 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x13e
02 0468f278 0f57235e 5536b5f4 0468f460 5536b5e8 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x150
03 0468f28c 55355b4f 0468f454 0468f460 0135cf54 mfc120ud!CCriticalSection::Lock+0x1e [f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxmt.inl @ 111]
04 0468f37c 55356b2e 00000003 0468f54c 0468f460 CommonManager!CCommonManager::GetManager+0x3f 
05 0468f454 012c538e 00000003 005ad478 0468f658 CommonManager!GetCommonManager+0x2e 
...
0a 0468f858 76f698f2 0135cf54 73bcc10f 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0b 0468f898 76f698c5 012d7a80 0135cf54 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0c 0468f8b0 00000000 012d7a80 0135cf54 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

0:003> ~5kbn
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 043bf8c8 76f7eb4e 00000234 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x15
01 043bf92c 76f7ea32 00000000 00000000 0135cf54 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x13e
02 043bf954 0f57235e 5536b5f4 043bfb3c 5536b5e8 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x150
03 043bf968 55355b4f 043bfb30 043bfb3c 0135cf54 mfc120ud!CCriticalSection::Lock+0x1e [f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxmt.inl @ 111]
04 043bfa58 55356b2e 00000003 043bfc28 043bfb3c CommonManager!CCommonManager::GetManager+0x3f 
05 043bfb30 012c538e 00000003 005b2428 043bfd34 CommonManager!GetCommonManager+0x2e 
...
0a 043bff34 76f698f2 0135cf54 73efc6e3 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0b 043bff74 76f698c5 012d7a80 0135cf54 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0c 043bff8c 00000000 012d7a80 0135cf54 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

0:003> ~4kbn
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 041df7dc 76f7eb4e 00000234 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x15
01 041df840 76f7ea32 00000000 00000000 0135cf54 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x13e
02 041df868 0f57235e 5536b5f4 041dfa50 5536b5e8 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x150
03 041df87c 55355b4f 041dfa44 041dfa50 0135cf54 mfc120ud!CCriticalSection::Lock+0x1e [f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxmt.inl @ 111]
04 041df96c 55356b2e 00000003 041dfb3c 041dfa50 CommonManager!CCommonManager::GetManager+0x3f 
05 041dfa44 012c538e 00000003 005affe8 041dfc48 CommonManager!GetCommonManager+0x2e 
...
0a 041dfe48 76f698f2 0135cf54 73c9c71f 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0b 041dfe88 76f698c5 012d7a80 0135cf54 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0c 041dfea0 00000000 012d7a80 0135cf54 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

0:003> !handle 234 f
Handle 234
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x100003:
         Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  6
  Name          <none>
  Object Specific Information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting

0:003> !cs 5536b5f4
-----------------------------------------
Critical section   = 0x5536b5f4 (CommonManager!oInstance+0x2C)
DebugInfo          = 0x0058a640
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x234
SpinCount          = 0x00000000

0:003> !critsec 5536b5f4

CritSec CommonManager!oInstance+2c at 5536b5f4
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    7
*** Locked

0:003> dt RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION 5536b5f4
TRExecutor!RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
   +0x000 DebugInfo        : 0x0058a640 _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG
   +0x004 LockCount        : 0n-15
   +0x008 RecursionCount   : 0n0
   +0x00c OwningThread     : (null) 
   +0x010 LockSemaphore    : 0x00000234 Void
   +0x014 SpinCount        : 0

0:003> ? 0x1 & (-0n15)
Evaluate expression: 1 = 00000001

0:003> ? (0x2 & (-0n15)) >> 1
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000

0:003> ? ((-1) - (-0n15)) >> 2
Evaluate expression: 3 = 00000003
```

Comment: Deadlocks happen for two **and only two** reasons:  lock escalation, and different lock order.  Lock escalation occurs when you try something like changing a read lock to a more restrictive write lock.  **ALWAYS** obtain your locks in the same order and **NEVER** escalate a lock and you will never have deadlocks.  Otherwise, you **WILL** have deadlocks.

Comment: That critical section looks corrupted. An unlocked critical section normally has a lock count of `-1`. Is there a chance you are not matching enters and leaves?

Comment: The code is very simple and I do not think so until now. Of course, there can be some unusual exceptions that I do not know ...